# Can't find a persistence unit named cinemaReservationPersistenceUnit in deployment "javakurs3.final.project.cinema.war"

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have a JBoss EAP 6.1.0.GA (AS 7.2.0.Final-redhat-8) and I want to deploy a java web-project that uses JPA. I use with Eclipse / Maven and upon deploying the application I recieve the error:

Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011047:
Can't find a persistence unit named cinemaReservationPersistenceUnit  in deployment "javakurs3.final.project.cinema.war"

This is my project structure in Eclipse:

[image]

After having read some of the related questions here, for example:

[JBoss7.1.0: Can't find a persistence unit named null in subdeployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880595/jboss7-1-0-cant-find-a-persistence-unit-named-null-in-subdeployment)

I was not able to find a solution to my Problem
This is my persistence.xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="cinemaReservationPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create.update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Could you please help?

Answer (score 2):

As you package project in war file you need to move persistence.xml under resources/webapp/WEB-INF folder.

Comment: I think you are not right. I have just successfully deployed another Java web-project that had the persistence.xml under the same structure as the project above and the deployment was successful

Comment: Like this: @Stateless(mappedName = "FilmService")
public class FilmService {

 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "cinemaReservationPersistenceUnit")
 private EntityManager em;

Comment: Try to rename META_INF on  META-INF